# Mixing Appcelerator/Titanium or Rhodes with native code

Tags: iphone, android, titanium, appcelerator, rhodes

We're about to build an app for both iPhone and Android, and it would (of course) be glorious to only build one application that could work on both platforms. My question is, how easy is it to drop out of these cross-platforms into native code for certain views/activities?

In other words, if I find that Titanium is terrible for a particular task, can I just write that in Objective-C for iPhone and Java for Android or does that involve a bunch of hacks? I'm hoping we'll be able to build the basic stuff cross-platform, but I'd still like to be able to drop to native code if I start hitting snags or some hardware feature is poorly supported. We're leaning towards Titanium since we (as a shop) are unfamiliar with Ruby, but Rhodes is something we're definitely looking into as well.

From what I've read, the jury is out on these frameworks, so I'd like to have fallback options in case the app becomes buggy/unwieldy halfway through. I realize that a lot of this depends on exactly what you want to do with the app, but we're still trying to figure out what we CAN do cross-platform first...

Comment: PhoneGap also has a plugin/extension model you can use for this sort of thing, if you would be willing to consider them. I'd put the odds of Rhodes having something for Java/Objective-C code a bit lower, though it's not completely out of the question.

Comment: I have written some phoneGap plugins and honestly, I find them easier to implement than the modules for Appcelerator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write modules for each of the platforms, how easy it is to drop out and integrate them into you application would depend upon what you are trying to accomplish.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/iphone/module_sdk

http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android/module_sdk